# Typescript sorting array with objects on multiple properties

Tags: arrays, typescript, sorting

I like to sort an array with objects that have multiple properties. My objects have a string called name and a boolean called mandatory.

First i want to sort on age, next on the name.

How do I do this?

Ordering by age is easy...:

```
this.model.mylist.sort((obj1: IObj, obj2: IObj => {
    if (obj1.age < obj2.age) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (obj1.age > obj2.age) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
});
```

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 6):

Well, you only add comparation for case when the two age values are the same. So something like this should work:

```
this.model.mylist.sort((obj1: IObj, obj2: IObj) => {
    if (obj1.age < obj2.age) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (obj1.age > obj2.age) {
        return 1;
    }

    return obj1.name.localeCompare(obj2.name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. The method compares the current and next values and adds comparison to the case when the two age values are the same. Then assume the column name in order based on age.

```
private compareTo(val1, val2, typeField) {
    let result = 0;
    if (typeField == "ftDate") {
        result = val1 - val2;
    } else {
        if (val1 < val2) {
            result = - 1;
        } else if (val1 > val2) {
            result = 1;
        } else {
            result = 0;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

-

```
this.model.mylist.sort((a, b) => {
    let cols = ["age", "name"];

    let i = 0, result = 0, resultordem = 0;

    while (result === 0 && i < cols.length) {
        let col = cols[i];
        let valcol1 = a[col];
        let valcol2 = b[col];
        let typeField = "string";

        if (col == "age") {
            typeField = "number";
        }

        if (valcol1 != "null" && valcol1 != "null") {
            resultordem = this.compareTo(valcol1, valcol2, typeField);

            if (resultordem != 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    return resultordem;
});
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer?

Comment: It's quite simple, the method compares the current and next values and adds comparison to the case when the two age values are the same. Then assume the column name in order based on age.

Comment: Please add this explanation to your answer.